# Error con botones de Apache y Mysql desativados

Tags: xampp

Abri el panel de control de Xampp y los botones de Apache y mysql y los demas estan todos desativados, en pocas palabras no se pueden clickear

adjunto foto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, intenta abrir el XAMPP desde la carpeta raíz que mayormente es en `C:\xampp`

Comment: EL log que se muestra ahí debajo dice que no encuentra los binarios que usa para iniciar los servicios y por eso desactiva las opciones. Revisa la configuración o la forma como inicias xampp

Comment: Si yo de hecho estoy abriendo el archivo de esa carpeta que se llama xampp-control o es otro? @lsanchezo

Comment: lo inicio o ejecuto abriendo el archivo xampp-control de la carpeta xampp en el disco c @Alfabravo

Comment: Intenta iniciar el `xampp-control` como administrador, pero desde la consola. Abre el CMD como administrador usas el `cd [ruta]` para dirigirte a la carpeta del XAMPP y ejecutas `start xampp-control.exe`

Comment: me salio el mensaje 'Windows no puede encontrar el archivo  xampp-control.exe, asegurese de que el nombre este escrito bien e intente nuevamente" sin embargo habia otro archivo .ini lo abri con el mismo comando y me salio esto:    [Common]
Edition=
Editor=notepad.exe
Browser=
Debug=0
Debuglevel=0
TomcatVisible=1
Language=English
[EnableModules]
Apache=0
MySQL=0
FileZilla=0
Mercury=0
Tomcat=0    @lsanchezo

Comment: Eso ocurre porque no estás ingresando la ruta correctamente.  Lo probé y debe salir esto más o menos en la consola: `C:\xampp>start xampp-control.exe`

Comment: yo ingrese esa misma ruta y me dio el error de arriba @lsanchezo